# why images has index.php in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a ready laravel project.The images are stored in the public/assets and they are displayed correct locally but on the server the path look like http://www.----//public/index.php/assets/dist/img/160x160.jpg i.e it adds index.php. the css and js files in public are loaded correct
I use 
 asset('public/assets/img/...gif') for images
and the same for js
 asset('/assets/dist/js/....js') 
and my .htaccess on the root lokks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

where is the problem

Comment: Did you change your .htaccess? And if yes, why? And could you show how you load images, do you use the `asset()` function, or do you use absolute paths?

Comment: I use asset function :  {{asset('public/assets/img/...gif') }} I mentioned the .htaccess file and I am not the programmer who makes the config another one did it

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to never change the **.htaccess** file unless it is server operation. 
There are two things you need to check:
1. Use the default .htaccess file and then check run the project.

IF this not works then you can try this:

1. Go to vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php
2. Press CTRL + F and search asset
3. Your default asset function should look like this if no changes are made by developers

   function asset($path, $secure = null)
   {
   return app('url')->asset("/".$path, $secure);
   }

Comment: I am not the person who make the vendor and it"s:
        return app('url')->asset($path, $secure); I try to change it to the one you have sent but the css files unloaded

Comment: Can you look in asset function, if "index.php" mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Actually the code you shared in the comment looks fine. So there must be some other reason.

Comment: there is no index.php

Comment: Okay, Can you check one more thing. Goto the server.php file and see if this line of code is like this:
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

Comment: $uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';